# How to Capture Appt_Write Event in VBA when Appointment Object is Clicked and Dragged at the Same Time

Tags: vba, outlook

I am trying to capture the appt_Write event on calendar appointment objects.  The code below works well for every case EXCEPT when a user selects the appointment and drags it in one click.

Is there a better way to set the appt object so that I can capture the appt_Write event for any appointment on any calendar?

```
Private WithEvents objExplorer As Outlook.Explorer
Private WithEvents appt As Outlook.AppointmentItem

Public Sub Application_Startup()
Set objExplorer = Application.ActiveExplorer
End Sub

Private Sub objExplorer_SelectionChange()
 If objExplorer.CurrentFolder.DefaultItemType = olAppointmentItem Then
    If objExplorer.Selection.Count > 0 Then
      Set appt = objExplorer.Selection(1)
    End If
  End If
End Sub


Private Sub appt_Write(Cancel As Boolean)
'Do something with Appt Object here.  When a user clicks and drags,
'this write event has already fired by the time the Appt object is set.
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use Items.ItemChange event on the folder, but it only fires after the item is changed.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use objExplorer_SelectionChange, instead go through all appointments in the current folder and attach appt_Write event listener to all items there (when your app is starting). Also, attach the event listener to ItemAdd on AppointmentsFolder.Items, so when the user creates an appointment then attach appt_Write event listener to that item too. That way you will always be able to listen on Write event.